# imageview dissapears when setting width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to add imageviews dynamically to a table. To do this, I use the following code:

```
public void showLetter(String aLetter){
    TableLayout letterTable = (TableLayout ) findViewById(R.id.letterArea);
    TableRow letterRow = (TableRow) letterTable.getChildAt(0);      
    ImageView newLetter = new ImageView(this);      
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("a", "drawable", getPackageName());
    newLetter.setBackgroundResource(imageResource);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);
    newLetter.setLayoutParams(params);
    letterRow.addView(newLetter);
}
```

When I try to run this code, the image is not shown when calling the showLetter function. When I don't set the layout parameters of the newLetter, this function works and the image is shown. Does anybody know why I can't set the layout parameters of this image without it dissapearing?

This is the xml file containing the table in which the images should be added:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/letterArea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/submitWord"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_gap"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_gap"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap" >

    <TableRow app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/blocksize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/blocksize"
            android:background="@drawable/scrabble_a" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/blocksize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/blocksize"
            android:background="@drawable/scrabble_b" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)` from `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);` and check...

Edit

Ok what i saw in your cod is that the parent of your ImageView is TableRow and not LinearLayout

You can check this once

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 50);
```

insetd of

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);
```

Comment: This did not have any influence on the behaviour. The image is still not shown.